# GD: Making white background for PNG transparent

Tags: php, gd

I have a PNG watermark image with transparent background. But randomly it generates a white background instead of staying transparent.

```
// Watermark
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');
list($mwidth, $mheight) = getimagesize($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');

// Combinde watermark image with image already generated in $dst
imagecopy($dst, $watermark, $tnWidth-$mwidth-5, $tnHeight-$mheight-5, 0, 0, $mwidth, $mheight);
```

Solution is to add:

```
imagealphablending($dst, true);
imagesavealpha($dst, true);
```

Complete code:

```
// Watermark
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');
list($mwidth, $mheight) = getimagesize($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');

imagealphablending($dst, true);
imagesavealpha($dst, true);

// Combinde watermark image with image already generated in $dst
imagecopy($dst, $watermark, $tnWidth-$mwidth-5, $tnHeight-$mheight-5, 0, 0, $mwidth,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save `$dst` with an alpha channel, not `$watermark`.

```
// Watermark
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');
list($mwidth, $mheight) = getimagesize($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');

imagealphablending($dst, false);
imagesavealpha($dst, true);

// Combinde watermark image with image already generated in $dst
imagecopy($dst, $watermark, $tnWidth-$mwidth-5, $tnHeight-$mheight-5, 0, 0, $mwidth, $mheight);
```

Comment: Just adding imagealphablending($dst, true); imagesavealpha($dst, true); did the trick. Thanks you for getting me on track.

Answer (score 0):

Try imagecopymerge instead of imagecopy

EDIT: try this code:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$dst = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');
list($mwidth, $mheight) = getimagesize($docRoot . '/images/misc/watermark.png');
imagecopymerge($dst, $watermark, $tnWidth-$mwidth-5, $tnHeight-$mheight-5, 0, 0, $mwidth, $mheight, 100);
imagejpeg($dst,'',90);
imagedestroy($dst);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but for me to get it to work I commented out these two lines from my code:

```
imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
imagesavealpha($image_2, true);
```

so my code looked like this:

```
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng("example26_".$acct.".png");
$image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('example27.png');
imagealphablending($image_1, true);
imagealphablending($image_2, true);
//imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
//imagesavealpha($image_2, true);
imagecopy($image_1, $image_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1350, 250);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image_1);
```

now the two images merged and preserved the transparency, with those two lines it was generating a random white background, hope this helps others with the same issue